# How to use singleton and static late binding toghter in php father class

Tags: php, static, singleton

I am trying to create a father class like:

```
class CommonModel extends \Common\Model\CommonModel {

protected static  $_instance = null; //singleton
/**
 * singleton
 * @return null|static
 * @Date 2017/4/7 14:06
 */
public static function instance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new static();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
```

UserModel and UserThirdModel implements the CommonModel

when I create
 $user =  UserModel::instance();   //an user instance is created

$userThird = UserThirdModel::instance();//  userModel retured.

I see the problem comes from   `"if(!isset(self::$_instance)){"`
my question is how to create different instance based on different model

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn `$_instance` into an array of instances by class name using `get_called_class()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

First change

```
protected static  $_instance = array(); //singleton array
```

and then use `self::$_instance[get_called_class()]` such as...

```
public static function instance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance[get_called_class()])){
        self::$_instance[get_called_class()] = new static();
    }
    return self::$_instance[get_called_class()];
}
```

Comment: I still have some questions!                                                                      
when I put  'function test(){ echo __CLASS__;}' in commonClass.              $a = new classA() // classA extends commonClass;                                when $a->test(); //the result is "commonClass"  why? it should be "classA",I think,becasue An object function is called, not in a static function;

Comment: `__CLASS__` will print the name of the class relative to what line of code it exists at, `get_called_class()` will resolve the class at runtime and resolve any class extends.